# Net Core NLog.Web "aspnet-request:header" property usage?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, nlog

Is there any way to log all headers using "aspnet-request:header" property with one parameter? Or should I get headers one by one like "aspnet-request:header=MyHeader" and combine them into one parameter before insert? I have lots of headers and don't want to add them seperately, I need a quick way to log them if its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently only one at once header is supported, as it calls

`string header = httpRequest.Headers[this.Header];` [see source](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/blob/2ef9f14b21b75b2660457dd01c427cc92d1592d6/NLog.Web.ASPNET5/LayoutRenderers/AspNetRequestValueLayoutRenderer.cs#L123)

edit: you could plug it in NLog like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using NLog.Config;
using NLog.LayoutRenderers;
using NLog.Web.Internal;

namespace NLog.Web.LayoutRenderers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Render all headers for ASP.NET Core
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// <code lang="NLog Layout Renderer">
    /// ${aspnet-request-all-headers}
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
    [LayoutRenderer("aspnet-request-all-headers")]
    public class AspNetRequestAllHeadersLayoutRenderer : AspNetLayoutRendererBase
    {


        protected override void DoAppend(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
        {
            var httpRequest = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.TryGetRequest();
            if (httpRequest == null || httpRequest.Headers == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            foreach(var kpv in httpRequest.Headers)
            {

                if (header != null)
                {
                    builder.Append(kpv.Key);
                    builder.Append(=);
                    builder.Append(kpv.Value);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Register it (startup.cs)

```
    ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.LayoutRenderers
                        .RegisterDefinition("aspnet-request-all-headers", typeof(AspNetRequestAllHeadersLayoutRenderer  ));
```

See also [Extending NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Extending%20NLog)

usage

```
 ${aspnet-request-all-headers}
```

Comment: Will be there this all headers property? Do you plan this? Or if it is possible, I would like to make some development, add features to your code :)

Comment: Not sure if there is a demand, but I did have included now class to inlclude. See post. (no tested yet)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Julian :)